# How to pull trending news from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts

I would like to pull trending news from Facebook in *JSON*, in order to use it in other application, but I couldn't find a way to do this. I have tried:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search/type=trending&access_token=my_accesstoken
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/search/type=news&access_token=my_accesstoken
```

but neither work.

Can someone help me please? I would like to know the correct url and type for accessing it.

Comment: There is no API for trending news

Comment: Inventing undocumented parameters has never solved anything.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are trying to leverage is closed off to the public.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are looking for is [Keyword Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights.)

Which is not available to public anymore.